couldn't find package "PACKAGE_NAME" on the "npm" registry
I am trying to build an docker image for one of the web apps. I have tried building the docker image in my local and also successfully pushed it after building the image. The issue I am facing is more prominently while trying to build the image on server machine but I run into error with npm and yarnpkg registry. It says that one of the dependencies is not available. The error goes like the below:
error Couldn't find package "@/gallery@*" required by "photos@0.0.0" on the "npm" registry.
Yarn version: 1.22.22
Node Image: node-21:bookworm-slim
This is the exact error which I have now as while I'm typing this post, I can't seem to replicate the same error because I deleted the repo and re-cloned it and tried replicating, hence I don't get this same error now. But here's the very recently error
114.4 [4/4] Building fresh packages...
115.0 Done in 114.12s.
116.2 yarn run v1.22.22
116.2 $ yarn workspace photos next build --verbose
117.6 $ /node_modules/.bin/next build --verbose
117.8 error: unknown option '--verbose'
117.8 error Command failed with exit code 1.
117.8 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
117.8 error Command failed.
117.8 Exit code: 1
117.8 Command: /usr/local/bin/node
117.8 Arguments: /.yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.22.cjs next build --verbose
117.8 Directory: /apps/photos
117.8 Output:
117.8 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/workspace for documentation about this command. 117.9 error Command failed with exit code 1.
[+] Running 0/1 https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
⠼ Service ente-web
 Building 121.5s failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c yarn install && yarn build:photos --verbose" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

The Dockerfile which I am able to build on my local system but not on the server machine. below is the Dockerfile and compoes.yml file.
Dockerfile
# Stage 1: Build dependencies
FROM node:21-bookworm-slim as builder

WORKDIR .

COPY yarn.lock package.json ./
COPY . .  

# Default to yarn v1.22.22
ENV YARN_VERSION 1.22.22
RUN yarn policies set-version $YARN_VERSION

RUN yarn install && yarn build:photos && yarn build:accounts && yarn build:auth && yarn build:cast

# Stage 2: Final image (without node_modules)
FROM caddy:latest as caddy
WORKDIR /app

# Copy only necessary files from the build stage
COPY --from=builder /apps/photos/out /app/photos
COPY --from=builder /apps/auth/out /app/auth
COPY --from=builder /apps/accounts/out /app/accounts
COPY --from=builder /apps/cast/out /app/cast

# Expose ports
ARG PHOTOS=3001
EXPOSE ${PHOTOS}

ARG ACCOUNTS=3002
EXPOSE ${ACCOUNTS}

ARG AUTH=3003
EXPOSE ${AUTH}

ARG CAST=3004
EXPOSE ${CAST}

COPY <<EOF /etc/caddy/Caddyfile 
:${PHOTOS} {
  root * /app/photos
    file_server
}
:${ACCOUNTS} {
  root * /app/accounts
    file_server
}
:${AUTH} {
  root * /app/auth
    file_server
}
:${CAST} {
  root * /app/cast
    file_server
}
EOF

RUN echo "serving on ports ${PHOTOS} ${ACCOUNTS} ${AUTH} ${CAST}"
CMD ["caddy", "run", "--config", "/etc/caddy/Caddyfile"]

docker-compose.yml
services:
  ente-web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
      - "3002:3002"
      - "3003:3003"
      - "3004:3004"
    environment:
      - NEXT_ENTE_ACCOUNTS_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:3005
      - NEXT_ENTE_ALBUMS_ENDPOINT=https://localhost:3006
      - NODE_ENV=development
    restart: always

The Project is Ente.and I was getting the gallery dependency error for the gallery package.

I have tried checking if accidentally I changed yarn and npm registry's or something of that sorts, but turns out there was no change in the docker. I tried checking into in one of my previous builds (1 day when it worked) and there were no changes. I have also tried setting up the yarn registry in the dockerfile with yarn config set registry https://registry.yarnpkgs.com/ command and nothing changed.
I have re-cloned the project and redid docker builds.
Delete the yarn.lock and re-ran yarn install and other build commands.
Just incase, also updated and restart my server.
And near to every unique suggestion on this issue on yarn.

The expectations are that yarn install and yarn build:* (all apps) would complete and caddy will start serving the static files which are moved in the second build. This is what I have running in my local system as well, which is serving files right and as expected. Just like the attached screenshot

The yarn workspace photos next build --verbose is saying it doesn't know what the --verbose flag is. Try either removing it or moving it before the build subcommand: yarn workspace photos next --verbose build
